# Scrolling UITableView to valid index path throws error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Why would the following code throw this error?

```
if ([self.tableView.dataSource numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView] > 0 && [self.tableView.dataSource tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] > 1) {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

throws

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: section (0) beyond bounds (0).'

It's pretty early in the morning, but I'm stumped.

Comment: I'm stumped too. Are you sure it's that call to `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` that's throwing the error?

Comment: Positive.  Debugger is pegged at that line every time.

Comment: Where are you calling this code?  Also unrelated side note: I don't think you need to check if the number of sections is greater than 0 because all tables have at least one section even if you don't use sections explicitly so this check will always be true.

Comment: @Nebs I know, but I wanted to be explicit that all the arguments are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` just before the lines that you post.

I bet that the datasource is ready after the table is rendered and you call the `scrollTo...` method before rendering the table with the data in the datasource...

Comment: That may be correct, but it seems unacceptable to me since the table will then reload twice on view loading.  It sounds like what I really need is a callback to my delegate like "tableDidReload".  A tableview calls reloadData on itself automatically when a view is created, so when does that happen?  It seems like it should happen before viewDidAppear is called, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I don't see all your code, but I am sure that you may put the code that you've posted after the `reloadData`. I am pretty sure that you use `reloadData` after you fill the datasource...